# implementation of JS passing an argument of unknown type

Tags: javascript

I wonder about how JS language itself is implemented (under the hood)
I'm mostly interested in how arguments are passed to functions.
How does a function 'know' whether an argument is a primitive or an object? for example:

```
function foo(x) { console.log(x); }
foo(obj.valueOf()) // the type of the argument to foo is not known at compile time...
```

if JS is written in C, for example, then foo will get void*? or a union {double, char*, void*}

Comment: It will get a `JsValue[]`.

Comment: How the implementation works will depend on the specific implementation. There are several open source JS engines you could examine.

Comment: I wonder about how is it possible at all? in some implementation